# Web API Owin self host multiple applications

Tags: owin, self-hosting

We are trying to setup an owin self host service for multiple applications (app1, app2).

We'd like to use the same behavior of IIS where one application pool uses one AppDomain per application.

Here is the code we use:

```
using (WebApp.Start<WebServerStartup>(url: "http://localhost:9000/")) { ... }
```

... and the WebServerStartup implementation:

```
internal class WebServerStartup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
    {
        // Configure Web API for self-host. 
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        appBuilder.UseWebApi(config);
    }
```

How can we use multiple AppDomains for each application? Is there a way to declare multiple webapps using Webapp.Start(...) in separate AppDomains that would share the same port? Or is there some way to route the requests to various appdomains somehow by defining a route like app/api/{controller}/{id} instead of api/{controller}/{id}?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's no built in support for running the apps in separate domains. You'd want to start each new AppDomain and then run WebApp.Start inside.

Comment: That said, AppDomains offer minimal isolation. You're better off using separate processes if you want true isolation.

Comment: Since my original post I tried various approaches: 1/ creation of an in-memory HTTP server (based on test server) which is invoked by the main HTTP server using an OWIN middleware ; and 2/ per your remark: creation of a reverse proxy that redirect requests to other HTTP servers hosted in separate processes and using other ports.

The first implementation ended up working perfectly for WebApis. I have more issues regarding SignalR that I'm currently investigating... and I'll test your suggestion of using a reverse proxy

Comment: Why do you need the reverse proxy? http.sys/HttpListener can handle the port sharing for you.

Comment: Because I want one HTTP port for all applications since they are dynamically created and we don't want to open all firewall ports

Comment: You can do that with http.sys/HttpListener. It's already proxying requests for you.